# Update same table sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
  id  phy
   0   0
   1   8
```

I need to update phy when the inserting value is greater than the existing value.

Can I achieve this in single query?

I tried the following:

```
UPDATE SET phy = CASE WHEN phy < newValue then newValue end where id = 0;
```

It works fine if this is the case. IfnewValue is lesser, then it inserts null. I don't know how to set value for the `ELSE`  case.

Then I thought that I should use self join on the table but I didn't get the query correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
CASE WHEN phy < newValue THEN newValue ELSE phy END
```

So, if `phy >= newValue`, then `phy` field remains unaffected.

Hence, the `UPDATE` statement becomes:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET phy = CASE WHEN phy < newValue THEN newValue ELSE phy END 
WHERE id = 0;
```